# Yarn update not working because of a bug in node-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

When i installed nodejs 18.7.0 or the last one 20.5.0 on my WSL2 witn nvm
a folder is created in my home directory ==> .node-gyp/

In my nodejs project when i run "yarn" or "yarn update" i have this error :

```
  File "/home/ray/.node-gyp/18.17.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1
    'uv_library%': 'static_library',
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

when i open the file "commone.gypi" it looks truncated. it starts like that:

```
'uv_library%': 'static_library',

    'clang%': 0,
    'error_on_warn%': 'false',

    'openssl_product': '<(STATIC_LIB_PREFIX)openssl<(STATIC_LIB_SUFFIX)',
    'openssl_no_asm%': 0,

    # Don't use ICU data file (icudtl.dat) from V8, we use our own.
    'icu_use_data_file_flag%': 0,

    # Reset this number to 0 on major V8 upgrades.
    # Increment by one for each non-official patch applied to deps/v8.
    'v8_embedder_string': '-node.26',

    ##### V8 defaults for Node.js #####

    # Turn on SipHash f{
  'variables': {
```

i dont know why. Can you help please?

Thanks a lot

regards

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your project has some dependency not compatible with NodeJS 18 or 20. Before python invocation you can find which module common.gypi is coming from. In my case it was node-sass. For example:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: C:\Src\project\node_modules\node-sass\common.gypi
```

Try updating this dependency.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. The problem seems to be the version of Python. node-gyp specifies on their [README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#configuring-python-dependency) that we shoud use either python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 or 3.10

You need to set the version that will be used when installing the npm dependencies.
You can do it either by running `npm config set python /usr/bin/python3` or if it doesn't work with message "not a valid npm option", you can directly edit the npm config with `npm config edit` and adding two lines:

```
python=/usr/bin/python3
python3=/usr/bin/python3
```

Please note that I found the path of the python executable thanks to `whereis python3`

Once done, the node-gyp installation passed but the node-sass installation failed because I had to upgrade it (check the compatibility table on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)).
Now the install works as expected for me